# Database Security when hosted on client

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption

I have a database along with REST API for clients to access the data.  For performance and other reasons, I need to move the application along with the data to the client's physical server.  Is there a way for me to encrypt the data in the database, so the only way the client can get access to it is through API that I expose, and not by cracking MySql and getting at raw data. I do not want the client to see the data stored on my DB, as I feel they will steal it or share it.  What can I do to accomplish that?

One idea:
Is it possible to implement some form of one-way encryption, where its based on the lookup value provided in api.

e.g. api lookup by email, that is then gets one-way encrypted compared in the DB for match, and returns a record.  This way if they happen to look at my database, the can not see list of emails, all they see is data that is something similar /etc/passwd file.

Comment: MySQL does not have this feature. But your REST app could do the encryption for you. A skilled, determined cracker will always be able to get the data, it is a question of how much effort you are prepared to go in order to make them give up first.

Comment: I agree hiding the data is rather useless.  What if the data is out in the open, but encrypted in the way I described, with SHA-2 or 3(hasn't been cracked as far as I know)?  Since there is never a way to decrypt it.  Is there a vulnerability you can think of?  Aside from trying all the possible combinations of email addresses to look through, and comparing hash keys which is a futile exercise that I'm OK with.

Comment: Maybe your question isn't clear. `for clients to access the data` If clients are to access the data then a 1 way hashing method is not suitable as the point is you cannot get the original data back.

Comment: Well my client will be accessing the data via an api, they would have to supply an email address which I then encrypt, and then using the generated hash do a look up in a DB, and return other data( stored unencrypted) that is associated with that email.  But the sensitive data(email) is hidden.
I guess the improvement on that is to use the email as a decryption key for all the other data.

Answer (score 0):

No.

From the [10 Immutable Laws of Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx)

Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore

What you want is fundamentally impossible, without caveats. Always and everywhere.